# Higher Order Equation of Motions from Lagrangian / Action

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, classical-field-theory

I'd like to derive the equations of motion for a scalar field in a FLRW universe, where the metric, as well as the field, are perturbed. I think I should get scalar as well as tensorial expressions.

An abstract expression would suffice, e.g. for the background:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\phi}}=0
$$

The scalar field perturbation would depend on the full spacetime, whereas the background field depends only on time.

I think I should get something like

$$
\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial\phi^2}\delta\phi-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left(\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial\dot{\phi}^2}\dot{\delta\phi}\right)=0,
$$

but I am not sure, how the spatial derivatives of the scalar field perturbation come into play here and if the second term is correct.

How do I derive the higher order equations of motion from a Lagragian?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation under Generalizations for the Euler Lagrange equations of $n^{th}$ order

Comment: How would the e.g. the determinant of the metric or the Ricci scalar classify in such a generalisation? Is it a function of several variables and each perturbation of the metric is to be treated as one variable?